# Hadoop Cluster distributed in different sub-networks (Docker + Flannel)

Tags: hadoop, docker

I want to have Hadoop 2.3.0 in a multi bare-metal cluster using Docker. I have a master container and a slave container (in this first setup). When Master and Slave containers are in the same host (and therefore, same Flannel subnet), Hadoop works perfectly. However, if the Master and Slave are in different bare metal nodes (hence, different flannel subnets), it simply does not work (I get a connection refused error). Both containers can ping and ssh one another, so there is no connectivity problem. For some reason, it seems that hadoop needs all the nodes in the cluster to be in the same subnet. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ssh and ping are not enough. If you have iptables or any other firewalls, either you need to disable or open up the ports. You can set up the cluster, as long as hosts can communicate with each other and ports are open. Run `telnet <namenode> <port>` to ensure hosts are communicating on desired ports.

Answer (score 1):

I think having the nodes in separate flannel subnets introduces some NAT-related rules which cause such issues.

See the below link which seems to have addressed a similar issue
[Re: Networking Problem in creating HDFS cluster.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/P4uh7y383oo)

Hadoop uses a bunch of other ports for communication between the nodes, the above assumes these ports are unblocked.